# Directing output file name in a variable in awk

Tags: shell, awk

```
tmf@liphy$ cat data
5
3

tmf@liphy$ gawk -v "fileA"="testA" '$1<5{print $1 > "fileA"}' data
```

I want the output to go to testA. It goes to fileA instead. I tried various combinations of inverted commas. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. You are using double quotes `"fileA"` which makes it string and will be considered as output file name as fileA(NOT as a variable `fileA`) where output should be written, rather than use variable name named `fileA` like  `> (fileA)`.

```
gawk -v "fileA"="testA" '$1<5{print $1 > (fileA)}' data
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
5
3
```

Have you considered you could use the shell rather than awk for creating the file:

```
 fn="testA"
 awk '$1<5' file > "$fn"
```

(Note that `"$fn"` *is* quoted in this case...)

But RavinderSingh13's method works too:

```
 awk -v fileA="$fn" '$1<5 {print > fileA}' file
```

(Note that `"$fn"` *is* quoted since the shell is handling it but `> fileA` is **not** quoted since that is inside the awk script...)

Then, either case:

```
cat "$fn"   # "testA"
3
```

The takeaway is the variable expansions such as `"$fn"` need to be quoted in the shell but not inside of an awk script.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments. I tried many versions and it turned out that most quotes and the extra brackets can be deleted. The only important detail is not to put the quotes inside awk.

gawk -v "fileA"="testA" '$1<5{print $1 > (fileA)}' data

gawk -v fileA="testA" '$1<5{print $1 > (fileA)}' data

gawk -v fileA="testA" '$1<5{print $1 > fileA}' data

gawk -v fileA=testA '$1<5{print $1 > fileA}' data

fn="testA";
awk -v fileA="$fn" '$1<5 {print > fileA}' data

fn="testA";
awk -v fileA=$fn '$1<5 {print > fileA}' data

fn=testA;
awk '$1<5' data > $fn